# MongoCollectionFinder<T> : ICollectionFinder<MongoCollection<T>> how to register this component using Windsor Castle?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

```
public class MongoCollectionFinder<T> :     ICollectionFinder<MongoCollection<T>> 
{
    private readonly IDatabaseContext<MongoDatabase> _databaseContext;

    public MongoCollectionFinder(IDatabaseContext<MongoDatabase> databaseContext)
    {
        this._databaseContext = databaseContext;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find collection with specified name from database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collectionName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public MongoCollection<T> FindCollection(string collectionName)
    {
        var database = _databaseContext.GetDatabase();
        return database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
    }

}
```

I am registering above using this line in Installer

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ICollectionFinder<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(MongoCollectionFinder<>)).LifestyleScoped());
```

but it is throwing this exception

> {"Object of type
>   'MongoCollectionFinder`1[MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection`1[Application]]'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'ICollectionFinder`1[MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection`1[Application]]'."}

Answer (score 0):

You are registering a component for an interface which it does not implement.

This can be seen as follows. Using the registration line you have shown here, Windsor (3.3) appears to register fine. However, If you call `Resolve<xxx>()` you will get an exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoCollectionFinder`1[xxx]' to type 'ICollectionFinder`1[xxx]'.
```

Which is correct. `MongoCollectionFinder<xxx>` does not implement `ICollectionFinder<xxx>`, it implements `ICollectionFinder<MongoCollection<xxx>>`.

If you call `Resolve<MongoCollection<xxx>>()` you will get the following exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoCollectionFinder`1[MongoCollection`1[xxx]]' to type 'ICollectionFinder`1[MongoCollection`1[xxx]]
```

Again this is correct. `MongoCollectionFinder<MongoCollection<xxx>>` does not implement `ICollectionFinder<MongoCollection<xxx>>`, it implements `ICollectionFinder<MongoCollection<MongoCollection<xxx>>>`.

Comment: But why compiler is not giving an error? And then how i can remove dependency of MongoCollection from interface, as you can see what i am trying to, i want to have interface which returns MongoCollection<T> from mongoDB, but i dont want MongoCollection reference in my interface signature?

Comment: Then your signature needs to reflect what it is you want to return. If not MongoCollection, then some base class or interface that callers can rely upon.

Comment: The compiler is not giving an error because it is not a compilation error. If you were using the generic For<> method you would get a compile time error but you cannot use this method with open generic types.

Comment: MongoCollection is calss which is not implementing any interface, MongoDriver have two classes MongoCollection<T> which is inhertied from abstract class MongoCollection both of them not implementing any interface.

Comment: Then what base class or interface do you propose to return from from ICollectionFinder.FindCollection(), other than MongoCollection?

Comment: Since MongoCollection is MongoDB Driver class, and i don't have reference to my interface library. What i am trying to achieve is, have generic interface signature to get away with mongodb driver dependency?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Someone is going to call FindCollection(). How do they utilize the return value without knowing the return type.